# Como utilizar While em MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Como utilizar WHILE em MySQL?

Tentei com a seguinte expressão:

```
set @C = 5 while @C > 1 select dia from base_prov_chamada end while;
```

E obtive a seguinte resposta:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   correspondent to Your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'while @c > 1 select dia from base_prov_chamada end while' at
>   line 3

Minha versão do MySQL é 5.0.

Comment: Você não pode ter condicionais fora do procedimento armazenado no mysql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/while.html

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Se puder explicar melhor o problema que tem em concreto e, se possível, mostrar código que já tenha feito onde se encontre esse problema. Está demasiado ampla a sua pergunta, veja na [Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Não entendi o que você quer fazer, mas sua sintaxe está errada. Primeiro você precisa declarar a variável pra depois usar, mais ou menos assim:

```sql
DECLARE c INT DEFAULT 5;

while c > 1 
    select dia from base_prov_chamada;

    SET c = c - 1;
end while;
```

Isto precisa estar dentro de uma `PROCEDURE`, senão não funciona.

Comment: Entendi.Eu não sabia sobre a procedure.

Comment: Cigano Muito obrigado!

Comment: @DanielNure A resposta atende ao que você precisa? Então, por favor, marque a resposta como aceita (ícone em forma de "V" embaixo da pontuação) para o benefício da comunidade. Obrigado!

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Por favor dê uma olhada na [discussão sobre esse assunto no meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1425/74). Não tem problema em pedir para aceitar sua resposta, mas não precisa ter pressa. Obrigado.

Comment: @bfavaretto Li essa discussão já, e concordo só em parte. Tem gente que entra e nunca marca a resposta como aceita. E não necessariamente precisa ser minha resposta.

Comment: Ok, mas você poderia postar sua opinião no meta para a comunidade avaliar? Parece haver um consenso lá por enquanto. E a frase dá sim a entender que é sobre a sua resposta.

Comment: @bfavaretto Como esperado, a questão não foi aceita.

Comment: Acontece. O AP postou a pergunta e não apareceu mais no site :(

Answer (score 2):

No exemplo acima faltou o **`Do`** depois da condição **`Do While`**.

```
DECLARE c INT DEFAULT 5;

While c > 1 Do

    select dia from base_prov_chamada;

    SET c = c - 1;

End While;
```